# Can a density function in a closed ball have an unbounded expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a closed ball, $$\mathcal{F}=\{g:D(g,f)\leq\epsilon\}$$ for a distance measure, $$D(g,f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y)\log\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\mathrm{d}y$$ is there any density function $g$, which has an expected value equals $\infty$?

Notes: $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are density functions with $g(y)>0$ and $f(y)>0$. The expected value w.r.t. $f$ is known to be $<\infty$. The density function $f$ is given and known.

Thank you very much..

Comment: Is $f$ given? In other words, if $f$ is given (with finite exp. value), then does it exist a $g$ with distance from $f$ less or equal to $\epsilon$ s.t. $E[g]$ is not finite? Did I correctly understand?

Comment: $f$ is given and it can be any $f$ with bounded expected value. Yes your understanding is completely correct. For the distance |g(y)-f(y)| I can easily find a counter example but that counterexample doesnt hold for the closed ball with the KL divergence.

Comment: My answer just got unaccepted without explanation after roughly one year spent in the "accepted" status. One can only wait with trepidation for the next movement on this page...

Comment: @Did it is great to hearing from you. How are you? How is life? Unbelievable. How did you realize it? I thought $15/201k$ is almost negligable but not $20/4k$. The symmetrized density for $a=0.5$ is as follows $(1/5)((-3+2x)/(-1+x)^3+(3+2x)/(1+x)^3)$ which is integrable although $g$ is not.

Comment: @Did it is not personal. If the answer is correct please let me know. In this case first I must re-accept the question and second apologize for unaccepting it as it would be my mistake. I am only learning from you to apply the truth only, thats all I am doing.

Comment: Ah, so now you are implying that my answer would not be "correct"? Since the comment supposedly explaining why is meaningless (and since, needless to say, the answer is perfectly "correct"), I see no reason to continue this exchange. Nothing personal, indeed.

Comment: @Did you offended, understandable from your comment. I was not implying that though. All your answers are upvoted and almost all are accepted. It is pointless to speak about a very specific example as you said. I was however implying something, that is true. That is however not about this question it is about the fact that you closed my question and the other question waited for a long time to be opened. I became very upset. I meant if we are here to make everything perfectly correct, then this could even sound correct, although not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems difficult to expect that $g$ being close to $f$ for the entropy and $f$ being integrable could imply an integrability property of $g$. Assume for example that $f$ and $g$ are density probabilities on $(1,+\infty)$, with $$f(x)=\frac2{x^3},\qquad g(x)=(1-a)\frac2{x^3}+a\frac1{x^2},
$$
for every $x\gt1$, for some $a$ in $(0,1)$. Then $f$ is the density of an integrable distribution, $g$ is the density of a non integrable distribution, and
$$
D(g,f)=\int_1^\infty\left((1-a)\frac2{x^3}+a\frac1{x^2}\right)\,\log\left(1-a+\frac12ax\right)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
An integration by parts based on the functions $u$ and $v$ defined on $(1,+\infty)$ by
$$
u(x)=(1-a)\frac1{x^2}+a\frac1{x},\qquad v(x)=\log\left(1-a+\frac12ax\right),
$$
yields
$$
D(f,g)=\left.-uv\right|_1^\infty+\int_1^\infty uv'=\log\left(1-\frac12a\right)+a\int_1^\infty\frac{1-a+ax}{2(1-a)+ax}\,\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}
$$
The fraction in the last integral is at most $1$ hence
$$
D(f,g)\leqslant\log\left(1-\frac12a\right)+a\leqslant\frac12a.
$$
In particular, $D(f,g)\to0$ when $a\to0$ although the distribution with density $g$ is not integrable, for any positive $a$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the nice example. would there be any example when $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$? This question comes from my comparison of some distance measures. When it is total variation $\int|P-Q|\mathrm{d}\mu$, assume $f$ is standard Gaussian. When I take $g$ as $0.9*f+0.1\mathcal{N}(a,1)$ and when $a\rightarrow\infty$, then $g$ is still in the closed ball of total variation but the expectation also goes to infinity. However, this is not true for the KL divergence.

Comment: The support is not a problem: shift $f$ and $g$ to $(0,+\infty)$ and symmetrize both.

Comment: okaky understood. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: I used Mathematica once again. Shifted the densities to $(0,\infty)$ and symmetrized both. The expected value of $g$ is no more $\infty$. It is $\infty-\infty$ though for some $c$, the integral over $|c|$ tends to $0$. I think it is also non-sense that we have to name this expectation as indeterminate.